# R: Performing Gradient Descent Directly on Functions Instead of Data Points from the Function

Tags: r, function, optimization

I am using the R programming language. Using this link over here [https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~janastas/stochastic-gradient-descent-in-r.html](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Ejanastas/stochastic-gradient-descent-in-r.html) , I found a function that allows you to perform Gradient Descent on data points from a function:

```
gradientR<-function(y, X, epsilon,eta, iters){
      epsilon = 0.0001
      X = as.matrix(data.frame(rep(1,length(y)),X))
      N= dim(X)[1]
      print("Initialize parameters...")
      theta.init = as.matrix(rnorm(n=dim(X)[2], mean=0,sd = 1)) # Initialize theta
      theta.init = t(theta.init)
       e = t(y) - theta.init%*%t(X)
       grad.init = -(2/N)%*%(e)%*%X
       theta = theta.init - eta*(1/N)*grad.init
       l2loss = c()
      for(i in 1:iters){
          l2loss = c(l2loss,sqrt(sum((t(y) - theta%*%t(X))^2)))
          e = t(y) - theta%*%t(X)
          grad = -(2/N)%*%e%*%X
          theta = theta - eta*(2/N)*grad
            if(sqrt(sum(grad^2)) <= epsilon){
              break
            }
        }
  print("Algorithm converged")
  print(paste("Final gradient norm is",sqrt(sum(grad^2))))
  values<-list("coef" = t(theta), "l2loss" = l2loss)
  return(values)
}
```

As an example, I tried use this function to "optimize" y = x^3 - 2x - 5:

[image]

```
x = seq(1,1000, by=1)
y = (x^3) - (2*x) -5

gdec.eta1 = gradientR(y = y, X = x, eta = 100, iters = 1000)
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Error in if (sqrt(sum(grad^2)) <= epsilon) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Why this is error being produced?**

And does anyone know if some other gradient descent functions in R would allow you to "directly" optimize this function instead of generating points from this function?

Something like this:

```
func2 <- function(x) {
  x^3 - 2* x - 5
}

gradientR(func2, eta = 100, iters = 1000)
```

**Does anyone know if this is possible?**

Thanks!

**Note:** This works for the following example (from the website linked above):

```
> y = rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
> x1 = rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
> x2 = rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
> x3 = rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
> x4 = rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
> x5 = rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
> 
> ptm <- proc.time()
> gdec.eta1 = gradientR(y = y, X = data.frame(x1,x2,x3, x4,x5), eta = 100, iters = 1000)
[1] "Initialize parameters..."
[1] "Algorithm converged"
[1] "Final gradient norm is 9.80308529574335e-05"
```

I just don't know why it doesn't work for my example.

Comment: `grad` produces `NaN`s. Check that it is valid first?

Comment: Symbolic optimization is better done by finding the stationary points (here 3x²-2=0). Note that your function has no global minimum nor maximum.

Comment: By the way, what you want to do seems unreasonable. Gradient descent on a function would mean adding the opposite derivative to the function with a variable weight, and finding the optimum weight (for all x ?). This turns the initial univariate problem to a harder bivariate one.

Comment: are you trying to optimize a function? see `?optim` or even `?polyroot` for multivariate and `optimise/optimize/uniroot` for univariate. IN your case use `polyroot(rev(c(1,-2, -5)))` to find teh zeros of the function

Comment: The reason as to why you are not getting results is because you are diverging instead of converging. You end up getting infinity when then turns to NaN, hence cannot make the comparison with epsilon

Comment: Your function is not convex/concave hence do not try using gradient descent/etc. Those algorithms are to optimize functions. In your case, you need the zeros of a function. This is different from optimizing the function. use `polyroots`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that gradientR solves the problem you have and the question is getting it to work with your input.   There are several problems here:

1. One cannot pass a function to the gradientR.  y and X must be vectors or matrices.
2. Many optimization problems have scaling issues if you give them numbers that are very different.  This one is no different.  Use x/1000 instead of x.
3. Just to be clear on what the underlying problem being solved is, it is to find a coefficient vector b such that the sum of the squares of
   the residual vector `y - cbind(1, x) %% b` is minimized where y and x are known.  Several commenters interpreted the problem differently but if their interpretation is what you want then gradientR is not applicable and , anyways, the problem of maximizing or minimizing x^3-2x-5 has no finite solutions.
4. If you want to pass func instead of y then just write a simple wrapper, grad2, as shown below.

To fix the scaling issue use it with x/1000 and y as shown.

```
x = seq(1, 1000, by = 1) / 1000
y = (x^3) - (2*x) -5

gdec.eta1 = gradientR(y = y, X = x, eta = 100, iters = 1000)
str(gdec.eta1)
## List of 2
##  $ coef  : num [1:2, 1] -5.2 -1.1 <----------------
##   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "rep.1..length.y.." "X"
##   .. ..$ : NULL
##  $ l2loss: num [1:260] 101.44 50.34 25.5 13.83 8.86 ...

# check that lm gives the same coefficients
coef(lm(y ~ x))
## (Intercept)           x 
##   -5.200701   -1.098500 <----------------
```

Now define a function which takes func rather than y.  func must be such that func(x) is y.  We test it out at the end and it gives the same result.

```
# func must be such that func(X) gives Y
grad2 <- function(func, X, ...) gradientR(func(X), X, ...)

# test
x = seq(1, 1000, by = 1) / 1000
func <- function(x) (x^3) - (2*x) -5

grad2 <- function(func, ...) gradientR(func(x), ...)
gdec.etal2 <- grad2(func, x, eta = 100, iters = 1000)
str(gdec.etal2)
## List of 2
##  $ coef  : num [1:2, 1] -5.2 -1.1  <----------------
##   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "rep.1..length.y.." "X"
##   .. ..$ : NULL
##  $ l2loss: num [1:238] 141.66 69.93 34.71 17.59 9.57 ...
```

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck : thank you so much for your answer! just to clarify: based on the results of gdec.etal2 - what is the final answer? what value of "x" gives the lowest value of the function? I believe that the final answer should be approximately x = 2.09 . Where can I view this answer? Is it available within str(gdec.etal2)?

Comment: The arrows in the answer highlight the lines with  the coefficients that minimize the objective.  Note that we changed x = 1:1000 to x = 1:1000/1000 so it is not the identical problem to the one in the question but I assume you are just trying to figure out how all this works.